# Overfitting if I include datetime after splitting it into day, week, month? in python

Tags: python, datetime

I am using sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression() and KFold's to fit my data. There are about 15 columns and 6000 rows of data for products being sold. I have a datetime (Close_Date) and split it up into Day, Week, Month, Weekday.

```
date_selection = 'Close_Date'
user_data['Weekday'] = user_data[date_selection].dt.dayofweek
user_data['Week'] = user_data[date_selection].dt.week
user_data['Day'] = user_data[date_selection].dt.day
user_data['Month'] = user_data[date_selection].dt.month
```

Doing this I got an r2 score = 0.23 with KFold. However, if I also include the original datetime for Close_Date (as a number), I get an r2score = 0.99. My question is, am I overfitting the model?

```
#Making Close_Date a number. Note my first date of entry is 735390 (as a number):
user_data['Close_Date'] = user_data['Close_Date'].apply(lambda x: x.toordinal() - 735390)
```

In regards to the first comment, here's my code:

```
total=0
for _ in range(100):
    kf = cross_validation.KFold(len(X), n_folds=25, shuffle = True)
    for train_index, test_index in kf:
       X_train = X.iloc[train_index]
       y_train = user_data['Term_Begin_Date'].iloc[train_index]
       X_test = X.iloc[test_index]
       y_test = user_data['Term_Begin_Date'].iloc[test_index]

       lm = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
       mse = metrics.mean_squared_error(user_data['Term_Begin_Date'].iloc[test_index],lm.predict(X_test))
       total += metrics.r2_score(y_test, lm.predict(X_test))
print total / 2500.
```

Comment: Probably. What happens when you try cross-validation?

Comment: I run it through cross-validation with n_folds set to 25, and after doing that 100 times, I get an average r2 of 0.913 or so each time.

Comment: Okay. What does `Term_Begin_Date` mean (ie what you're trying to predict)? Does one of the features contain the amount of time between `Term_Begin_Date` and `Close_Date`?

Comment: Term_Begin_Date is the date I am predicting. And I drop the column that has the number of days between Close_Date and Term_Begin_Date. Basically, the client buys a product on the Close_Date and I try to predict the day they'll start using the product (Term_Begin_Date).

Comment: It does seem that I overfit my data. I also made the realization I never did get_dummies for weekday, week, month, years. So my r2 score of 0.9913 was not predicting the way I needed!